# Tweepy giving me Tweets all on same day

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get a random sampling of Tweets in the last year using Tweepy, but it keeps just giving me 2000 Tweets on the same day (today). How do I fix this?

```
search_term = "#ethereum -filter:retweets"
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search_term,lang='en', since_id='1345111141026914304', tweet_mode = 'extended').items(2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview) that [`API.search_tweets`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets) uses only “searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days."

You'll need to look into v1.1 premium or enterprise APIs or the Academic Research access level for Twitter API v2 for full-archive search.